# ios charts integer convert

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I'm using ios Charts 3.0 on the objc project. I had searched the answers on the stackoverflow but no correct results for me. I'm using horizon bar chart and pie chart in my project and tried using

```
yAxis.valueFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
yAxis.valueFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
```

for every axis as well as the custom formatter with this :

```
- (NSString *)stringForValue:(double)value
                        axis:(ChartAxisBase *)axis
{
    return [@((NSInteger)value) stringValue];
}
```

Both ways did not work for me. Could you guys please help to resolve this?

[image: Screen shots]

Comment: I have not been using Charts but you could try to print out the values and check the result instead of just returning them. Then you can check if probnlem is in the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the code below. I wrote it at Swift and don't know much Objective-C. I hope it helps. I'm using this for BarChart and it works like a charm.

```
let fmt = NumberFormatter()
fmt.numberStyle = .decimal
fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 0
fmt.groupingSeparator = ","
fmt.decimalSeparator = "."
yAxis.valueFormatter = DefaultAxisValueFormatter.init(formatter: fmt)
```

Comment: It's working for me after adding this formatter for the dataset. :)
' dataSet.valueFormatter = [[ChartDefaultValueFormatter alloc] initWithFormatter:numFormatter];'

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend IValueFormatter protocol with custom formatter class,

```
import Foundation
import Charts

// Custom value formatter class
class BarValueFormatter : NSObject, IValueFormatter {

    // This method is  called when a value (from labels inside the chart) is formatted before being drawn.
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double,
                        entry: ChartDataEntry,
                        dataSetIndex: Int,
                        viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
        let digitWithoutFractionValues = String(format: "%.0f", value)
        return digitWithoutFractionValues
    }

}
```

Now in your code initialise bar value formatter using custom class. It will remove all precision/franction values.

```
let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: <dataSetValues>, label: <stringValue>)
let valueFormatter = BarValueFormatter()
chartDataSet.valueFormatter = valueFormatter
```